# TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function(anonymous function)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatables, master-pages

I'm using jquery datatable in a page that has a slider as well. In my project I have a master page which contains some scripts at the end as shown here:

site.master.aspx

```
<body>
    -
    -
      <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
        <script src="js/default.js"></script>
        <script src="layerslider/js/greensock.js"></script>
        <script src="layerslider/js/layerslider.kreaturamedia.jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="layerslider/js/layerslider.transitions.js"></script>
    </body>
```

At the end of my default page there are some necessary scripts required for Jquery Datatable as shown bellow:

Default.aspx

```
 <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/jeditable/jquery.jeditable.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/dataTables/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/dataTables/dataTables.tableTools.min.js"></script>
```

If I move the script codes from master page to the Default.aspx page. The slider doesn't work. My current Error is :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bfxm.jpg)

If I leave them in master page the Jquery datatable doesn't work.

I have tried to remove some duplicate jquery scripts but it makes more errors.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bfxm.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Jquery noConflict?

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

```
<script>
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

    // Do something with jQuery
    j( "div p" ).hide();

    // Do something with another library's $()
    $( "content" ).style.display = "none";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning a table to datatable after the document has loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example-table').DataTable();

    });
```